# Getting Karma/Jasmine working for AngularJS project

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, jasmine, karma-runner

**UPDATE**:

I've resolved the problem. I had mistyped the filename for a dependency int karma config's `files` list. Very frustrating that I had to modify core angular files to log out this information for me. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22158035/363701) for more details.

**If anyone has insight on how better to debug similar issues, please comment or answer below.*

---

I've been having a heck of a time getting tests working on my Angular project.

I can get Karma/Jasmine to "*pass*" a test successfully, but only if I'm not calling `inject`.

**Tests**

```
describe("my filter", function() {

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('MyApp');
        // inject(function($injector) { });
    });

    // fails if `inject` line above is uncommented
    it('should be true', function() {
        expect(true).toBe(true);  
    });

    // always fails
    it('should still be true', inject(function (myFilter) {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    }));

});
```

**Karma Config**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        files: [
            '../bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            '../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'path/to/a/file/I/misspelled.js',
            '../build/js/scripts.js', // my app code all concatenated, etc..
            '../app/filters/myFilter/myFilter.test.js'
        ],
        exclude: [],
        reporters: ['progress'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
        autoWatch: false,
        browsers: ['Safari'],
        captureTimeout: 60000,
        singleRun: true
    });
};
```

**Gruntfile**

```
karma: {
    unit: {configFile: 'test/karma.config.js'}
},
```

I tried to keep all that above code as minimal as possible, but can paste more if its relevant; not really sure how far to go, as I'm completely confused as to where the point of failure is.

Running `grunt:karma` *works*

Karma starts up Safari fine, and it appears to resolve all my files as expected.

However, the `should still be true` test above fails, with the following stack trace:

```
Safari 7.0.2 (Mac OS X 10.9.2) my filter should still be true FAILED
    /Users/me/path/to/my/project/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3703:53
    forEach@[native code]
    forEach@/Users/me/path/to/my/project/bower_components/angular/angular.js:322:18
    loadModules@/Users/me/path/to/my/project/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3668:12
    createInjector@/Users/me/path/to/my/project/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3608:22
    workFn@/Users/me/path/to/my/project/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2138:60
Safari 7.0.2 (Mac OS X 10.9.2): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0.191 secs / 0.014 secs)
```

Does anyone have any insight? I've been pouring over Karma/Jasmine docs and tutorials, and have tried numerous things, but am somehow missing it. It's been my running theory that I'm loading the wrong *files* in the Karma config -- mostly because I haven't found a good description of precisely *what* should be loaded for *what* to work.

**UPDATE**

I've been digging into that stack trace, and trying to do some debugging / exploration

**`angular-mocks.js:2138`**:

```
injector = currentSpec.$injector = angular.injector(modules);
```

I did some `console.log()`s above that line, and got the following;

```
console.log(modules); // ['ng', 'ngMock', 'MyApp']
console.log(angular.injector); // function createInjector(modulesToLoad) { ... }
console.log(angular.injector(modules)); // fails with same stack trace as above
```

I *guess* this seems to imply that it failed to inject one of those three *modules*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, looks like I got to the bottom of it. I ended up going to all the file locations in the stacktrace and `console.log`'ing just about everything. I got some useful info by console.logging `e` above here:

```
throw $injectorMinErr('modulerr', "Failed to instantiate module {0} due to:\n{1}",
              module, e.stack || e.message || e);
```

Seems that I was, in fact having a problem with a typo in a file that was included. No clue why that stuff doesn't appear in the console in the first place.

Adding that log message gave me the following (and much more).

```
$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myMistypedModule due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'myMistypedModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15-build.2364+sha.7c34e1f/$injector/nomod?p0=angles
```